# How do I pass a string value from one form to another in c#?

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to pass a text value from a settings form to another form.
What I am trying to do is pass a string value form a textbox on the settings form to the main form.
The main form has a GunaUI2 Button (Which I am trying to control)

I was trying to use `public Form1 frmMain = new Form1();` to import my main form to my settings form.
Then I would try to change the text of the GunaUI2 Button with this code: `frmMain.btn_1.Text = textBox1.Text;`

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks
EB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to pass any value from a form to another form is by creating a second constructor to the form you want to pass the value to. For Example:

Let's say you want to pass string from form1 to form2 then the code would look something like this:

First create a second constructor in form2 like:

```
public Form2(string s)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            String_passed_from_Form_1 = s
        }
```

Then when you make the object of form2 in form1 code:

```
Form2 obj = new Form2("String Value to pass to form2");
obj.show();
```

Doing the above the string value will be stored in the vairable "String_passed_from_Form_1" and would be accessable in the other form.

Comment: thanks it's working perfectly! :)